# Why I have problem downloading iso file in android?

Tags: browser, downloading

Background: Our company monitor the network data usage and give warning to employee with high internet data usage. What I want to do is download the big file in my android phone because I have a unlimited data usage plan for it.

I wanted to download some linux iso from the internet but I want to do it in my phone. I had downloaded some big files ( 200-300mb, exe files ) back in some weeks and they are successful. I just click the link inside Dolphin Browser HD and it automatically popped up a prompt-to-save.

Today I tried to download some linux iso files ( 600-700mb ) and they were not successful either by clicking the link directly or put the link into a downloader app. But I can download them from my PC without problem ( of course I didn't download it actually ).

Dolphin Browser HD's progress bar stopped at about 1/10 and keeping loading, finally said "Web Page not available".

And the downloader said cannot connect to the server.

Do you have any idea? Here is one of the file I need to download:

http://download.fedoraproject.org/pub/fedora/linux/releases/17/Live/i686/Fedora-17-i686-Live-Desktop.iso

Comment: Phone networks aren't reliable for large file transfer.  Considering torrenting or using a download manager to guard against network errors.

Answer (score 2):

It's entirely possible that your carrier's network has noticed you downloading large files and throttled or shaped your bandwidth - particularly if that file put you over 2GB of data for the month, which it sounds like it would have.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to download DVD images, you probably hit the 4GB size limit of the FAT32 file system. This can only be circumvented by using another file system, such as NTFS or ext2/3/4. But, unfortunately, the odds are your phone doesn't support these formats, so you can't download files this large if you can't find them split into smaller parts.

Of course you can try to reformat your SD card as NTFS and see if the phone recognizes it, but don't hold your breath.

Comment: The files are just 600-700mb. Are there other possibilities?

Comment: Hmm, maybe the apps use the phone's internal memory as a temp location and it runs out of space. I'd suggest trying different apps and browsers, I read somewhere that Opera has a good download manager. Other than that, can't think of anything.

Answer (score -1):

Install [Astro File Manager](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.metago.astro) . Go to its `Preferences` from Options menu and check `Enable Browser Download`. Ignore warning and tap OK (the warning is fake; it has been patched). Now, you can download any type of files from web using Dolphin Browser HD.

Comment: This sounds like it's enabling download of arbitrary content, rather than having anything to do with large files.

Comment: @Matthew It also supports resuming, man..

Comment: It didn't solve the problem. Astro won't pop up.

Comment: @gunbuster Astro works silently..